# How to give space in the equation

Tags: equations

I would like to ask you on how to give some space (yellow highlighted) inside an equation as below screenshot.

[image: expected]

This is the code in overleaf with TeX Live version 2022.

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation} \label{eq:R2}
R_2(i) = (\frac{1}{m_i})(p_i+c_i+2w)   \forall i =1,\ldots,n
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

The current result is as follows.
[image: pdf]

Comment: Note that it is often nicer to read if one writes out a symbol like `\forall` when it is after an equation, aka `... \qquad\text{for all $i=1,\dots,n}`, one can even easily make a `\For` macro that essentially is `\qquad\text{....}` and thus hide the spacing in it such that is does not clog up your code.

Answer (score 5):

Just add `\quad`, `\qquad` etc between the two parts of the equation.

```
\begin{equation} \label{eq:R2}
R_2(i) = (\frac{1}{m_i})(p_i+c_i+2w) \qquad  \forall i =1,\ldots,n
\end{equation}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 possibilities for you to do this:

1. Using `\quad` or `\qquad`:

### Input (Using `\quad`):

```
\begin{equation} \label{eq:R2}
    R_2(i) = \left(\frac{1}{m_i}\right)(p_i+c_i+2w) \quad  \forall i =1,\ldots,n
\end{equation}
```

### Output (Using `\quad`):

[image]

---

### Input (Using `\qquad`):

```
\begin{equation} \label{eq:R2}
    R_2(i) = \left(\frac{1}{m_i}\right)(p_i+c_i+2w) \qquad  \forall i =1,\ldots,n
\end{equation}
```

### Output (Using `\qquad`):

[image]

---

---

2. Using `\hspace{#key}`, where #key is some unit of measurement, such as pt, mm, cm, etc:

### Input (Using `\hspace{1cm}`):

```
\begin{equation} \label{eq:R2}
    R_2(i) = \left(\frac{1}{m_i}\right)(p_i+c_i+2w) \hspace{1cm}  \forall i =1,\ldots,n
\end{equation}
```

### Output (Using `\hspace{1cm}`):

[image]

---

---

3. Using a sigle slash `\` sometimes:

### Input (Using `\` four times):

```
\begin{equation} \label{eq:R2}
    R_2(i) = \left(\frac{1}{m_i}\right)(p_i+c_i+2w) \ \ \ \  \forall i =1,\ldots,n
\end{equation}
```

### Output (Using `\` four times):

[image]

Comment: Note that the two last ones are not recommended. It is never a good idea to have random `\hspace`'s scattered around the code. With `\ ` (backslash space) it is easy to miss one, such that you have inconsistent spacing. Thus it is better to always encourage users to use `\quad` and `\qquad`

Comment: Personally I prefer to use \hspace{}, because it is simple and convenient, and the spacing control is much simpler to manipulate. If you want equal spacing every time, just define a command, for example \def\hsp{\hspace{1cm}}, and with this you are not bound to the measurements of \quad or \qquad

Comment: Here is a real life example of why users should not know about `\hspace`: `\chapter{Introduction\hspace{0.2pt}:
         \hspace{0.4pt}number\hspace{0.4pt},
         \hspace{0.6pt}algebra \hspace{0.4pt}and 
         \hspace{0.4pt}complex numbers} 
\vspace{-18pt}
` (I have it listed as an example of what not to do in an old talk of mine). Imaging having to be the editor on such a manuscript.

Comment: What did you mean to exemplify in this comment? It didn't make any sense to me this usage

Comment: That is what I mean, when users start adding `\hspace` all over, this is something we end up seeing. So it is better the average user never knows about `\hspace`. Similarly that the average user should never know that ``\\`` can be used in the text. `\hspace` should never be used in math.

Comment: I understand the confusion for beginners using commands like ```\hspace{}```. But they're valuable for learning; the more they're used, the more users understand their usefulness and use them judiciously. Neglecting them for novices may seem reasonable, but isn't optimal for teaching.